# Android: Animating FAB to top of dialog like SnackBar

Tags: android-animation, android-dialog, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I am showing a fab button on bottom of CoordinatorLayout. On top of that FAB, I want to show a dialog(animating it from bottom) and animate FAB to top of same dialog and make it work like close button for the dialog.

I know if we use CoordinatorLayout with FAB, SnackBar behave with same kind of animation but I want the same animation for dialog enter and exit too.

Is there any way I can achieve the same animation?

Answer (score 0):

To show your snackbar

```
public static void showSnackBar(@NonNull View view, @NonNull CharSequence text,
                                    @Snackbar.Duration int duration) {
        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);
        TextView snackTextView = (TextView) snack.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        snackTextView.setMaxLines(5);
        snack.show();
    }
```

Here view is your reference to coordinator layout

In your xml place your fab button like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/stream_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/stream_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>




        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/groupLoadingView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/postButton"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_newpost_button_selector"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue_color"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/stream_recyclerview"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```